# Is PARTITION BY automatically sorted?

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

Is the data returned by `PARTITION BY` automatically sorted by the fields that are used in the partition definition?

I mean, is the following `ORDER BY` clause redundant, because I already create a grouping by those fields inside the partition?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY product_type, product_count ORDER BY price) as row_num,
        product_type, product_count, ..., price 
    FROM mytable
    ORDER BY product_type, product_count, price
) as sub
WHERE sub.row_num <= 1
```

Comment: Window function need in sorting according the frame definition for to perform the calculation effectively. To achieve the effectiveness the server will perform the sorting in most cases (if there is no suitable index, of course).

Comment: ORDER BY in the subquery makes no sense - it will be lost in outer query.